# Horizontal Asymptote- Limits at Infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$. How would I find the $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\bigg)$?  I know that $\sin(x)$ oscillates periodically between $1$, and $-1$, so would the limit not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must use something called the squeeze theorem here. First of all, we know that $$-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$$
$$-4 \leq 4\sin(x) \leq 4$$
$$\frac{-4}{x^2+1}\leq \frac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1} \leq \dfrac{4}{x^2+1}$$

What the squeeze theorem allows is that if the 
$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac{-4}{x^2+1}\bigg) = \lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac{4}{x^2+1}\bigg)$, then that is also equal to $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\bigg)$.

$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac{-4}{x^2+1}\bigg) = 0$$
$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{4}{x^2+1}\bigg) = 0$$

THUS,

$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\bigg(\dfrac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\bigg) = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the limit of sin(x) doesn't exist, but look at the denominator. What happens to the overall expression as x gets large? The limit does exist.

Answer (score 1):

The oscillations don't matter here since the denominator grows indefinitely. Just note that
$$
0\leq\left|\frac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\right|\leq\frac{4}{x^2+1}
$$
and now use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to conclude that the limit as $x\to\infty$ of your function is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you more intuition about why the oscillation does not really matter:

[image]

On the other hand, mathematically, 
$$
\left|\frac{4\sin x}{x^2+1}\right|\leq\left|\frac{4}{x^2+1}\right|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\left|\frac{4\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\right|\le\frac{4}{x^2+1}\rightarrow 0$. So your asymptote is $y=0$